# Writing a file using UCS-2 Little Endian encoding

Tags: php, file, encoding, character-encoding

I need to write some info in a file with UCS-2 Little Endian with PHP, so that when I open up that file in my editor, the encoding is set to UCS-2 Little Endian as shown in attached picture.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever manage this @silvercover? I'm now trying to do the same thing except UCS-2 Big Endian and have not managed to achieve this so far using the iconv function as @Evert has suggested in his answer.

Comment: @richhallstoke no I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iconv: `iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE', $string);`
Additionally you need to prepend BOM to a resulting file (`"\xFF\xFE"`).

My Notepad++ then set encoding as in your picture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this question was very important question at that moment and my incapability in solving that resulted to bad memories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iconv() to convert character sets. Check 'iconv --list' on the command line for a list of supported encodings.